# how main() can call non-static nethods in Java?

Tags: java, oop, static

Well. I am new to Java. I know that main needs to be static method. But I have read that an static method can call only other static methods ? Then how come we can call non-static methods ? Its a confusion rather than a question. For example

```
 public class Function
    {
    public static int side = 10,area,vol;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("programme to find area and volume");
        Function fu = new Function();
        fu.calarea();
    }
    public void calarea()
    {
        area = side*side;
        System.out.println("finished calculating area now calling volume");
        calvol();
    }
    public void calvol()
    {
        vol = area*side;
        System.out.println("finished calculating volume now calling display");
        display();
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("side of a square ==>"+side);
        System.out.println("area of a square ==>"+area);
        System.out.println("volume of a square ==>"+vol);
    }
    }
```

In here, main() is a static method. So, it must call static methods only ? How come, it can call calarea() ? If I am right by creating a object ??

EDIT:

I had thought the same. And I know how to call static methods. I only want to know that if it is possible to call non-static methods(by any means), then why it is said that an static method can call only other static methods ?

Comment: It can only call static methods *directly*.  By creating an instance of an object, you can then call member methods of that object.

Comment: Yes; you're calling instance methods, on an instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I have read that an static method can call only other static methods ?

That is either a misstatement or a misreading.

A more correct statement of the "rule" is that a static method cannot call instance methods without a specific (non-null) instance reference.  Or to put it another way, `this` is not valid in a static method, so it cannot be used explicitly or implicitly to make method calls.

Your example doesn't break the rule ... in either form.  It is using an non-null object reference, and it is not using `this` explicitly or implicitly.

---

Most of the other subquestions are "mooted" by the above but ...

> If I am right by creating a object ??

Yes.  It is necessary to create the object in order to have an object reference that you can use to call the instance method.  There is no other way to call an instance method.

Comment: +1. This answer to the point, clarifies OPs confusion about the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes by using instance you can call instance methods.

```
calarea()
```

is instance method, so, you need to create an instance of `Function` class and call `calarea()` on that instance reference.

Comment: Well, This is what I also thought. Then, what is meant by saying that a static method can call only static methods ? I know how to call them by the way.

Comment: @GauravTiwari: As Stephen C said, correct statement would be, static method can;t call instance methods without using instance reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are other flavours but this one should get it across.

if you have a class with mixture of static and instance methods, the static methods can't call the the instance ones. 
e.g

in pseudo code

```
class SomeClass
{
static void IDoSomething()
{
   UDoSomething();  
}

void UDosomething
{
}
}
```

would give you an error but

```
class SomeClass
{
static void IDoSomething(SomeClass argSomeClass)
{
   argSomeClass.UDoSomething();  
}

void UDosomething
{
}
}
```

would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You need to create instance (object) of the class Function. So the right code is:

```
Function f = new Function();
f.calvol();
```